# bash: Is a directory error

Tags: linux, bash, git, minix

So I encounter this "bash: Is a directory" error while trying to run the following command on my Arch Linux VirtualBox. GNU bash version 4.3.30(1).

```
/home/minix git clone git://git.minix3.org/minix src
```

I have checked if I have git installed. And it is in `/usr/bin/git`.

I am completely lost, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is shown because you're trying to run `/home/minix` as a command (with `git clone ...` as its parameters).

Why is that directory name there? Did you add it for a specific reason? Did it get copypasted off the web along with the rest of the command? If not, the following should be enough:

```
git clone git://git.minix3.org/minix
```

Comment: Yes I took it from a tutorial slides and the OS was Knoppix (unknown to me) and I mistakened the directory with the command line. Pretty stupid... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Knoppix is just a Linux no different from Arch.

Comment: mixed up $ and # at the end of the pwd.